# Books on optimal control

Tags: reference-request, optimization, book-recommendation, control-theory, optimal-control

I am planning to start studying optimal control, especially the bang-bang problem.

What elementary texts or documents on the subject would you recommend?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

- Lawrence C. Evans, [An Introduction to Mathematical Optimal Control Theory](https://math.berkeley.edu/~evans/control.course.pdf), Department of Mathematics, University of California, Berkeley.

Answer (score 7):

A good reference is the recent book Calculus of Variations and Optimal Control Theory: A Concise Introduction by Daniel Liberzon http://press.princeton.edu/titles/9760.html

Optimal Control Theory: An Introduction (books.google.com/books?isbn=0486135071) by Kirk (1970, 464p) is an older, somewhat more engineering-oriented book, reprinted by Dover Books. It is a good classic.

Start with 1 or both of these. Most other texts are heavier reading than both of these together.